# Prevent direct url access in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, restrict

I have made a ecommerce website, where after placing order I redirect users to success page with order number. If order number doesn't exist,then id would be passed. But there is a problem when neither there exist order number nor order id then too success page is showing some previous orders placed if direct url is pasted. Eg : `www.mywebsite.com/order/success/5000`, here 5000 doesn't exist so it should redirect me to 404 error page.

> MY_controller

```
 $order_num = $this->order_model->getOrderNum($order_id);

 if(empty($order_num)){
    $order_num = $order_id.'/id';
 }

 $redirect_url = 'order/success/'.$order_num.'/';
?>
<script>
    function redirect_success(url) {
        location.assign(url);
    }
    var success = '<?=$redirect_url?>';
    redirect_success(success);
</script>
```

> My_Model

```
 public function getOrderNum($order_id = ''){
   $returnVal = false;

   $sql = "SELECT order_num FROM order_table";
   $sql .= " WHERE order_id = '{$order_id}'";    

 $query  = $this->db->query($sql);

  if($query->num_rows() > 0){
     $result    = $query->result_array();
     $row       = $result[0];
     $returnVal = $row;
   }

   return $returnVal['order_num'];
 }
```

Comment: Man, I don't have much of knowledge about codeigniter, but you should probably put a check before redirecting to make sure the id exists, something like: `if(isset($order_num)){ //redirect`

Comment: Its not working @HawasKaPujaari .It is stil showing me some previous order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to check in the order/success controller whether the page referer is coming from the order/place page.

So in order/success, if http_referer header is not set or not from order/place, redirect to 404.

Add in order/success/ controller:

```
if( !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "order/place") === -1 ) {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    redirect('/page404');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jackie this solved my problem partially.When user would try to access success url directly its redirects to 404 error page.But when user refreshes the success page again, it show previous order.I want to prevent user to prevent from page refresh also. Further help would really be appreciated !!!

Comment: You can achieve this easily by placing $_SESSION['success_viewed'] = false; in order/place, then in order/success add $_SESSION['success_viewed'] = true;. Then in the above checking code, add if( !isset($_SESSION['success_viewed']) || $_SESSION['success_viewed']==true ) { redirect('/page404'); }. Remember to add session_start(); before using session.